# Param is missing or the value is empty - validations are sent in request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I have a model called Wish:

```
class Wish < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :global_product

  validates :global_product_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Here are the wish routes:

```
            user_wishes GET    /users/:user_id/wishes(.:format)                                wishes#index
                        POST   /users/:user_id/wishes(.:format)                                wishes#create
          new_user_wish GET    /users/:user_id/wishes/new(.:format)                            wishes#new
         edit_user_wish GET    /users/:user_id/wishes/:id/edit(.:format)                       wishes#edit
              user_wish GET    /users/:user_id/wishes/:id(.:format)                            wishes#show
                        PATCH  /users/:user_id/wishes/:id(.:format)                            wishes#update
                        PUT    /users/:user_id/wishes/:id(.:format)                            wishes#update
                        DELETE /users/:user_id/wishes/:id(.:format)                            wishes#destroy
```

Once the user creates a global_product, they are directed to its show page. From there I created a button to create a wish. Global_product_id is a foreign key on the Wish table, so they're creating a wish out of the global_product.

Based on the route I thought the required parameters were user_id and global_product_id:

```
<%= link_to 'Add this product to my wish list', user_wishes_path(:global_product_id => @global_product.id,
                                                                 :user_id => current_user.id),
                                                                 :method=> :post,
                                                                 class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

In the wish controller, here is the create method and wish_params:

```
  def create
    @wish = Wish.new(wish_params)
    @wish.save
    if @wish.save
      redirect_to 'index'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def wish_params
    params.require(:wish).permit(:global_product_id, :user_id)
  end
```

Here is the exact error in my last request:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"y1vzGG5+CoyGS4XAFJ6sQPlD5XyNRfSMA14r4lWsUh3N1FA8Uz/Q7HNUMWOpsPQyBILgpjVxJCM552757yNsjw==", "global_product_id"=>"25", "user_id"=>"1"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with this request as in rails console I am able to create a new wish using Wish.create(user_id: 1, global_product_id: 25). I had tried passing in wish and global_product into my link_to request but same error and it doesn't look like I would need those. All that is required is user_id and global_product_id, which are in the failed request.

Comment: Make sure you sent the params as they're being expected `params[:wish] = { "global_product_id"=>"25", "user_id"=>"1" }`

Comment: @SebastianPalma Which file determines the correct order of params? I modified my model validations, link_to arguments, and wish_params to all require :global_product_id followed by user_id, but am seeing the same error.

Comment: Try momentarily to remove the `require(:wish)` part, if it returns something different to a 400 Bad Request status, so is the way you're adding to params to your `link_to` helper.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Without `require(:wish)` the error is a 302 instead of a 400 as before. `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"iMmyCtE4qDm4T+INjhdzvSA6aIkobSjaj0BHl7xGngugaw4VyoU2IREXxGL5btlZ8OzTVRrSvBetIpBdTaEaDw==", "global_product_id"=>"4", "user_id"=>"1"}
Unpermitted parameters: :_method, :authenticity_token`. I'll look more at the `link_to` params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending your params as:

```
{"global_product_id"=>"25", "user_id"=>"1"}
```

While your code:

```
params.require(:wish).permit(:user_id, :global_product_id)
```

expects it to be:

```
{"wish" => {"global_product_id"=>"25", "user_id"=>"1"}}
```

---

So you need to fix either your `wish_params` method or your `link_to` call to match.

You can fix `link_to` to be like:

```
<%= link_to 'Add this product to my wish list', 
             user_wishes_path(user_id: current_user.id, 
                              wish: {
                                global_product_id: @global_product.id,
                                user_id: current_user.id
                              }),
             method: :post,
             class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The user who commented on my original post suggested this too. I tried having global_product_id beforoe user_id and vice versa in both files, and yet I'm still receiving the same error. Could something else be wrong with my request in link_to?

Comment: It’s not the order, you are sending a wrong structure. You need to have the current hash nested into a ‘wish’ hash as show in my answer

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the suggested solution. Try to use my recommended `link_to`. it should work :)

Comment: Ah, I see it's not the order.. Do you know why using that block above for `link_to` results in this error? `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"wishes", :id=>"27", :wish=>{:global_product_id=>27, :user_id=>1}}, missing required keys: [:user_id]`? In my original block it was hitting post instead of index and it wasn't missing `user_id` either.

Comment: `user_id: current_user.id, wish: { global_product_id: @global_product.id, user_id: current_user.id }` This is how the hash passed to `link_to` should look like .. answer updated!

Comment: Thank you! The record is now finally created. I'm getting a 302 redirect error that stems from my create method, but that is a separate issue and one I'm sure I can resolve. Selecting your answer now :)